# Doctrine - постоянное соединение с базой данных PostgeSQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, fastcgi

Не могу понять, как работает соединение с БД в Doctrine.

Использую Symfony 4, запущен встроенный php-сервер.

Есть условный контроллер:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

    use App\Entity\TaskTest;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    class TaskTestController extends AbstractController
    {

        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();       

            $sqlGet = 'SELECT * FROM some_test';
            $preparedSQL = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sqlGet);
            $preparedSQL->execute();

            $allObjects = $preparedSQL->fetchAll();
            return new Response('$allObjects'.$allObjects);
        }
    }
?>
```

В продакшене предполагается использовать сервер nginx с PHP FastCGI. В связи с этим вопрос: будет ли EntityManager всегда создавать новое соединение с БД и при вызове $entityManager->getConnection() возвращать новый объект? Или соединение с БД будет где-то "висеть" открытым? Хотя, если так, то мне непонятно, как это возможно, ведь жизненный цикл php, насколько я знаю, предполагает, что после каждого исполнения процесс умирает.

Буду благодарен за ответы

Comment: В течение всего выполнения будет возвращаться один и тот же коннект, ассоциированный с заданным менеджером сущностей (в Вашем случае - с дефолтовым)
Доктрину все же лучше использовать как полноценную ORM

Comment: @abu, то есть, вне зависимости от того, что скрипт уже отработал? А если пользователь, например, закроет страницу и снова откроет, будет ли всё ещё поддерживаться старое соединение или будет создано новое?

Comment: соединение держится только на время выполнения скрипта. это зависит не от доктрины, а от реализации PDO. После окончания работы скрипта соединение с БД закрывается. В настройках php можно выставить персистентное соединение, однако тогда соединения будут бесконтрольно плодиться, пока не забьются все соединения к базе. Потому такие настройки не рекомендуются

Comment: @abu, понятно, спасибо!

Comment: @abu вы писали о том что _Доктрину все же лучше использовать как полноценную ORM_  . Хотел спросить, почему ?